# document.getElementsByclassName is not a function

Tags: javascript

i want to create tab using javascript. but its not working. it saying that my document.getElementsByclassName is not a function.

```
        <script>
            function openTab(evt, objectiveName) {
                var i, produkoverview, menuproduk1;
                produkoverview = document.getElementsByClassName('produkoverview');
                for (i = 0; i < produkoverview.lenght; i++ ) {
                    producoverview[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                menuproduk1 = document.get.getElementsByClassName('menuproduk1');
                for (i = 0; i < menuproduk1.lenght; i++) {
                    menuproduk1[i].className = menuproduk1[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                document.getElementsById(objectiveName).style.display= "block";
                evt, currentTarget.className += " active";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

just want to create a tab. so when "overview tab is clicked" the overview content is showing. when "Item List" is clicked, it showing it conten too

Comment: `document.get.getElementsByClassName` What is `document.get`? If the error is exactly as you said, `document.getElementsByclassName is not a function`, it's because Javascript is case-sensitive

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is what you are looking for. No `.get.` and a capital C.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()`; `.length`; `evt.currentTarget`; capitalization and spelling tell the computer you want to do totally different things. Get in the habit of looking for typos.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing correctly the method to get elements by class name.

You are using:

`document.get.getElementsByClassName('menuproduk1');`

when in fact, the correct way is:

`document.getElementsByClassName('menuproduck1');`

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).